# Implement multiple users in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Does anyone know if their exists a bundle that supports multiple user types?

In my example I want a generic User class (e.g. FOSUser) that I will extend from to use for my CompanyUser class and EmployeeUser class, so those 2 classes will have all the features of a User but with their own class properties and methods.

From what I read it looks like FOSUser only supports a single type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Bundle. You should use Groups or if there is no other ways UserEntities extending the UserBaseModel. These should be available through a custom UserProvider

Comment: I found this last night but not had time to check it out yet. https://github.com/netmeansnet/NmnMultiUserBundle

Answer (score 0):

you can use [RollerworksMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/rollerworks/RollerworksMultiUserBundle)